# How to show slider inputs based on selected radio buttons in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I was wondering how to get multiple slider options to appear and hide other slider options, when a radio button is selected. I am currently running into an error sourcing message. I am currently trying to have the radio buttons reactive so that when a button is selected only certain slider inputs are shown. For example, when SEIR is selected I want to disable the alpha and delta slider.

```
 library(shiny)
library(markdown)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyhelper)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

   ui <- fluidPage( 
  
  navbarPage(title = span("Spatial Tracking of COVID-19 using Mathematical Models", style = "color:#000000; font-weight:bold; font-size:15pt" ), 
             tabPanel("Model",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                          div(
                            id = "dashboard", 
                            
                            shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                            radioButtons("modelSelect",
                                         label = "Epidemic Model",
                                         choiceValues = list("SEIR","SEIRD","SVEIRD"),
                                         choiceNames = list("SEIR","SEIRD","SVEIRD"),
                                         selected = character(0),
                                         inline = TRUE,
                                         width = "1000px"),
                            #withMathJax(),
#     sliderInput("alpha",
                                    #                 label = "Daily Vaccination Rate α:",
                                    #                 min = 0, max = 1,step = 0.001, value = 0),
                                    #     
                                    #     sliderInput("beta",
                                    #                 "Daily Exposure Rate (Beta):",
                                    #                 min = 0, max = 1,step = 0.001, value = 0.009),
                                    #     
                                    #     sliderInput("gamma",
                                    #                 "Daily fraction that move out of the exposed compartment to the infectious compartment (gamma):",
                                    #                 min = 0, max = 1,step = 0.001, value = 0.010),
                                    #     sliderInput("sigma",
                                    #                 " Daily fraction that move out of the infectious compartment to the recovered compartment (sigma):",
                                    #                 min = 0, max = 1,step = 0.001, value = 0.065),
                                    #     
                                    #     sliderInput("delta",
                                    #                 "Daily fraction that move out of the infectious compartment to the dead compartment (delta):",
                                    #                 min = 0, max = 1,step = 0.001, value = 0.002),
                                    # ),
                                    # 
                                    # 
                            
                            
                            #α, β, γ, σ, δ, λ
                            
                            pmap(list(c("alpha","beta","gamma","sigma","delta"), c(0,1,0.001,0), c(0,1,0.001,0.009), c(0,1,0.001,0.010), c(0,1,0.001,0.065), c(0,1,0.001,0.002)), ~
                                   sliderInput(..1,
                                               strc_c(..1, ':'),
                                               min = ..2 max = ..3,step=0.001, value = ..4 ),
                              
                                 
                                ), 
                              
                                 
                                 
                                 
                                 
                                 
                                 
                       
                          actionButton("go","Run Simulation"),
                          actionButton("resetAll","Clear values"), 
                          
                          
                          mainPanel(
                            
                              
                            )
                          )
                        )
                               
                               
                               
                               
                               
                      )
                      
                      
             )
  )
)



# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  

  
  observeEvent(input$modelSelect, {
    if(input$modelSelect == "SEIR"){
      map(c("alpha","delta"), ~disable(.1))
      map(~ c("beta","gamma","sigma" ), ~enable(.1))
    }else if(input$modelSelect == "SEIRD"){
      map(c("alpha",), ~disable(.1))
      map(c("beta","gamma","sigma","delta"), ~enable(.1))
    }else{
      map(c("alpha","beta","gamma","sigma","delta"), ~enable(.1))
    }
  })

  
} 


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: 1. Please include all the non-base R packages that you are using in the code. 2. Did you mean `fluidPage` instead of `fluidpage` ? 3. You have a missing closing bracket in `ui` code. 4. After correcting 1, 2 and 3 I get an error `argument "mainPanel" is missing, with no default`.

Comment: Hello @RonakShah, my apologies for the late response. Here is the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `conditionalPanel()` function to show or hide a panel based on a condition. In this example, if 'Option 1' is selected then a, b, and c sliders will appear visible.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Dashboard", 
             tabPanel("Model", 
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                          radioButtons("modelSelect",
                                       label = "Example Model",
                                       choiceValues = list("optionOne","optionTwo","optionThree"),
                                       choiceNames = list("Option 1","Option 2","Option 3"),
                                       selected = character(0),
                                       inline = TRUE,
                                       width = "1000px"),
                          
                          conditionalPanel(
                            condition = "input.modelSelect == 'optionOne'",
                            sliderInput("a",
                                        label = "a:", 
                                        min = 0, max = 1,step = 1, value = 0),
                            sliderInput("b",
                                        "b:", 
                                        min = 0, max = 1,step = 1, value = 0),
                            
                            sliderInput("c",
                                        "c:", 
                                        min = 0, max = 1,step = 1, value = 0)
                            ),
                      
                          sliderInput("d",
                                      " d:", 
                                      min = 0, max = 1,step = 1, value = 0),
                          
                          sliderInput("e",
                                      "e:", 
                                      min = 0, max = 1,step = 1, value = 0),
                        ), mainPanel()
                      )
             )
  )
)
  server <- function(input, output, session) { 
    
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Using `shinyjs`:

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("Dashboard", 
             tabPanel("Model", 
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                          radioButtons("modelSelect",
                                       label = "Example Model",
                                       choiceValues = list("optionOne","optionTwo","optionThree"),
                                       choiceNames = list("Option 1","Option 2","Option 3"),
                                       selected = character(0),
                                       inline = TRUE,
                                       width = "1000px"),
                          #avoiding code repetition
                          map(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), ~
                                sliderInput(.x,
                                            str_c(.x, ':'), 
                                            min = 0, max = 1,step = 1, value = 0))
                        ),
                        mainPanel()
                      )
             )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  
  observeEvent(input$modelSelect, {
    if(input$modelSelect == "optionOne"){
      map(c('d', 'e'), ~disable(.x))
      map(~ c('a', 'b', 'c'), ~enable(.x))
    } else if(input$modelSelect == "optionTwo"){
      map(c('a', 'b', 'c'), ~disable(.x))
      map(c('d', 'e'), ~enable(.x))
    } else {
      map(letters[1:5], ~ enable(.x))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Edit: To have different slider values use replace inside the ui `map()` for `pmap()`.

```
pmap(list(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), c(0, 10, 11, 12, 20), c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50), c(5, 10, 15, 30 , 45)), ~
       sliderInput(..1,
                   str_c(..1, ':'), 
                   min = ..2, max = ..3,step = 1, value = ..4))
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your response. I was wondering if I were to change the slider inputs to have different values would I just create the separate slider widgets and remove c("a","b","c","d","e") and str_c(.x, ":")?

Comment: @student_1999 You can use `pmap()` to have each slider with unique values.  Check the edit.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it!